# Entity Framework: How to avoid Discriminator column from table?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following table created using Entity Framework **Code First** approach.

1. How do I modify the C# code so that the unwanted Discriminator column is not created in the database? Are there any attributes to achieve this?
2. How do I make the foreign key column named `PaymentID` instead of `Payment_ PaymentID`? Are there any attributes to achieve this?

Note: Runtime version for EntityFramework.dll is **v4.0.30XXX**.

[image]

**CODE**

```
public abstract class PaymentComponent
{
    public int PaymentComponentID { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
    public string MyType { get; set; }
    public abstract int GetEffectiveValue();
}

public partial class GiftCouponPayment : PaymentComponent
{
    public override int GetEffectiveValue()
    {
        if (MyValue < 2000)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return MyValue;
    }
}

public partial class ClubCardPayment : PaymentComponent
{
    public override int GetEffectiveValue()
    {
        return MyValue;
    }
}

public partial class Payment
{
    public int PaymentID { get; set; }
    public List<PaymentComponent> PaymentComponents { get; set; }
    public DateTime PayedTime { get; set; }
}

//System.Data.Entity.DbContext is from EntityFramework.dll
public class NerdDinners : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public NerdDinners(string connString) : base(connString)
    { 

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        modelbuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public DbSet<GiftCouponPayment> GiftCouponPayments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClubCardPayment> ClubCardPayments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
    {                
        GiftCouponPayment giftCouponPayment = new GiftCouponPayment();
        giftCouponPayment.MyValue = 250;
        giftCouponPayment.MyType = "GiftCouponPayment";

        ClubCardPayment clubCardPayment = new ClubCardPayment();
        clubCardPayment.MyValue = 5000;
        clubCardPayment.MyType = "ClubCardPayment";

        List<PaymentComponent> comps = new List<PaymentComponent>();
        comps.Add(giftCouponPayment);
        comps.Add(clubCardPayment);

        var payment = new Payment { PaymentComponents = comps, PayedTime=DateTime.Now };
        db.Payments.Add(payment);

        int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you override conventions other developers will struggle understanding your schema. It is more beneficial to learn and use the conventions, i.e. you won't have to ask questions when reading other developers' code or the default generated code and you won't have to write additional code either.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

TPH inheritance needs special column which is used to identify the type of entity. By default this column is called `Discriminator` and contains names of derived entities. You can use Fluent-API to define different column name and different values. You can also use your MyType column directly because it is actually a discriminator but in such case you cannot have that column in your entity (column can be mapped only once and if you use it as discriminator it is already considered as mapping).

The name of foreign key column can be again controlled with Fluent-API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
{
    modelbuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    // Example of controlling TPH iheritance:
    modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentComponent>()
            .Map<GiftPaymentComponent>(m => m.Requires("MyType").HasValue("G"))
            .Map<ClubPaymentComponent>(m => m.Requires("MyType").HasValue("C"));

    // Example of controlling Foreign key:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>()
                .HasMany(p => p.PaymentComponents)
                .WithRequired()
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("PaymentId"));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add attribute [NotMapped] if the property not going to mapped to column.

Comment: Also, adding [NotMapped] as class attribute helps when you don't want EF to map your subclasses to database tables

Comment: Thank-you, exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: If you prefer to use Fluent API for this instead of attribute/annotations you can edit your _DbContext_ and in the _OnModelCreating_ method add: **modelBuilder.Ignore<TypeToIgnore>();**

Comment: @kape123: that solved my problem, I derived from an entity but only to add some collections not to be stored in the db.

Comment: This worked for me. By adding `[NotMapped]` to the base class, it ignored the class but used the properties for it in the mapped child class.

Answer (score 5):

Could also use Table per Type (TPT).

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

> Table per Type (TPT)
>
> Table per Type is about representing inheritance relationships as
>   relational foreign key associations. Every class/subclass that
>   declares persistent properties—including abstract classes—has its own
>   table. The table for subclasses contains columns only for each
>   noninherited property (each property declared by the subclass itself)
>   along with a primary key that is also a foreign key of the base class
>   table.
>
> Implement TPT in EF Code First
>
> We can create a TPT mapping simply by placing Table attribute on the
>   subclasses to specify the mapped table name (Table attribute is a new
>   data annotation and has been added to
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace in CTP5.
>
> If you prefer fluent API, then you can create a TPT mapping by using
>   ToTable() method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccount>().ToTable("BankAccounts");
    modelBuilder.Entity<CreditCard>().ToTable("CreditCards");
}
```

Comment: Be aware that TPT is not recommended for EF when performance is an issue. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh949853  under 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

As you're using subclasses, the Discriminator column is required to distinguish between each type of your subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to remove Discriminator column and get column named PaymentId as discriminator instead, therefore solving both your questions. Based on Microsofts Fluent Api original documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
public enum MyEnum
{ 
    Value1, Value2
}

public class MyBaseClass

{ 
    [NotMapped]
    public MyEnum PaymentId { get; protected set; }
}

public class DerivedOne: MyBaseClass
{
    public DerivedOne()
    {
        PaymentId = MyEnum.Value1;
    } 
}

public class DerivedTwo: MyBaseClass
{
    public DerivedTwo()
    {
        PaymentId = MyEnum.Value2;
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<MyBaseClass> MyBaseClass { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyBaseClass>()
            .Map<DerivedOne>(x => x.Requires("PaymentId").HasValue((int)PaymentId.Value1))
            .Map<DerivedTwo>(x => x.Requires("PaymentId").HasValue((int)PaymentId.Value2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid Discriminator column from table you just need to add annotation [NotMapped] over your derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Since both "GiftCouponPayment" and "ClubCardPayment" derives from "PaymentComponent" EF will not use separate tables and will need that column. If you want a different behaviour you would have to override the default table access and map the fields to your classes (which I think you don't want to do) Not sure if there is an easy way to to this. From entity first, I know that there is a way through the template which creates the tables. 
The same is for the foreign key column name. EF uses that way of creating the name for key/foreignkey names. If you want to format the table as you like, you have to do it all yourself, which leads to the question why use EF then at all.
Is there a particular reason why you want to do that, other than cosmetics?