# Type Per Table Mapping in CodeFirst in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a membership module something like below (I simplified it)

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public int UserDetailId {get; set;}

   public virtual UserDetail UserDetail {get; set;} 
}

public class UserDetail
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  public string PassWord {get; set;}

  public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```

Then I am using this structure by many project but with some improvement like below

```
public class CustomUser : User
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public string EMail {get; set;}
}
```

The relationship between CustomUser and UserDetail should be one to one and the Discrimininator field should be discarded. I am using fluent api. But I could not do it succeffully.

[image: The Table Creation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify table mappings for each type:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>().ToTable("CustomUsers");
```

---

Discriminator column is required, if you want to store hierarchy in single table. But you can specify your own name and values for this column. Here is an example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Map<User>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue(0))
            .Map<CustomUser>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue(1));

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.UserDetail)
    .WithRequired(ud => ud.User)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

For these classes

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class CustomUser : User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

EF will generate following tables with one to one relation (with `UserId` as FK):

[image]

Comment: I do not want to create a table for each User type. I want only one and it is the CustomUser for this example. Why I need to specify a mappping for User and CustomUser ?

Comment: @RyuKaplan It's not clear what you want to achieve. You are asking about *Type Per Table Mapping*, but now you are saying that you need *Type Per Hierarchy Mapping*. Can you please describe what you want to achieve, and what exact problem you have now?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Let me explain again. I do not want to have more than one User table. One application can use directly the User class but the other one can use a CustomUser class that inherits from User class. And UserDetail class always constant and doesnt change. Now I have a CustomUser and I want it to be one-to-one relation with UserDetail. But their foreign key properties couldnt set successfuly as you saw on the picture. Also I want to discard the discriminator column because I will always have one user table.

Comment: @RyuKaplan OK, I see what you want. But discriminator column is required if you are storing several types in single table. You can provide your own column name and value for it, if you want.

Comment: +1 Really appeciated for solution.

You said that "discriminator colmn is required if I store several types". Actually I need only one user type to store user not one more. Then What is the job of discriminator column here ? There is no UserType as 0, always will be 1. So is there any way to discard it ?

Comment: Ok. I did User class as abstract and it did the job for me. But this time I always will create a CustomUser that inherits from User.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11631373). It could be that you are missing something in using Fluent-API.