# Entity Framework Code First TPH duplicate/redundent Discriminator column?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have followed the accepted answer this SO link [Entity Framework: How to avoid Discriminator column from table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630515/entity-framework-how-to-avoid-discriminator-column-from-table) to create the single table named Entities of TPH for multiple types.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
{
    modelbuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    // Example of controlling TPH iheritance:
    modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentComponent>()
            .Map<GiftPaymentComponent>(m => m.Requires("MyType").HasValue("G"))
            .Map<ClubPaymentComponent>(m => m.Requires("MyType").HasValue("C"));
```

The application actually works well. However, in table Entities, while the "MyType" column is holding the discriminators like "G" and "C", however, there exists a column "Discriminator" with data "(Undefined)".

If I have Fluent API codes like:
                .Map(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("G"))
                .Map(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("C"));

then in table "Entities", the redundant column is now named as "Discriminator1".

Here's my Fluent API codes in real:

```
public DbSet<Dealer> Dealers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
public DbSet<BizEntity> BusinessEntities { get; set; }

public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    //Table per inheritence
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
        .Map<Customer>(d => d.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("C"))
        .Map<Dealer>(d => d.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("D"))
        .Map<Person>(d => d.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("P")).ToTable("Entities");
```

Person, Customer and Dealer are concrete classes, while Entity and BizEntity are abstract.

How to have proper TPH without that redundant Disscriminator column?

Answer (score 0):

UPD: I have same problem.
You can remove redurant discriminator by adding third option like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentComponent>()
          .Map<GiftPaymentComponent>(m => m.Requires("MyType").HasValue("G"))
          .Map<ClubPaymentComponent>(m => m.Requires("MyType").HasValue("C"));
          .Map<SomePaymentComponent>(m => m.Requires("MyType").HasValue("S"));
```

And column "Discriminator" goes away.
I think this is a bug of EF.