# How to disable inheritance relationship mapping entityframework core

Tags: inheritance, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
[Table("Rectangle")]
public partial class Rectangle
{
     int length;
   int breath;
}
[Table("Rhombus")]
public partial class Rhombus
{
    int length;
   int breath;
    int angle;
}
```

just for sake of code reusability i need like this

```
  [Table("Rhombus")]
   public partial class Rhombus:Rectangle
    {
        int angle;
    }
```

but it creates discriminator field because of TPH

so how to disable inheritance relationship so that i can extent a entity just for code reusability or any other workaround to achieve this.

Comment: You can't remove the discriminator when using inheritance with Table-per-Hierarchy. You can have some measure of control over what that column looks like though, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630515/entity-framework-how-to-avoid-discriminator-column-from-table).

Comment: You can extract common properties to interface and derive both types from that interface. At present there is no way you can have 2 types included model in hierarchy in CLR model but not in database TPH.

Comment: ef core really hasn't kept any opening to do any kind of layering using inheritance. you can neither extend to or from any class used in the DBContext

Answer (score 1):

Consider **using abstract class** to disable inheritance.

And as @smit mentioned you may also **use an interface instead**.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me insane. Make the base class abstract worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Shape
{
   int length;
   int breath;
}

[Table("Rectangle")]
public partial class Rectangle : Shape
{
}

[Table("Rhombus")]
public partial class Rhombus : Shape
{
    int angle;
}
```